# Find all modules with finite number of elements over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Find all non-isomorphic $R$-modules that each have four elements.

The answer given was $$R/(x^2);\quad R/(x^2+x);\\R/(x^2+x+1);\quad R/(x^2+1);\\ R/(x+1) \oplus R/(x+1);\quad R/(x+1) \oplus R/(x)$$

Now I am having quite some difficulty determining why these are not isomorphic. Prior to this question, I believed for each degree $2$ polynomial $f(x)$ in $R$, $$R/(f(x))\cong\{a+bx\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\}\cong R \oplus R$$

Now I think this would only be true if $f(x)$ is irreducible and I know the only irreducible polynomial with degree $2$ here is $x^2+x+1$. I also realize that the isomorphism with $R \oplus R$ is for the underlying abelian groups. Would the isomorphism with $R \oplus R$ still hold for each quotient by the ideal generated by a monic polynomial with degree $2$, just the operation of multiplication on $R \oplus R$ is different for each? So the rings are nonisomorphic?   I also cannot see why $R/(x+1) \oplus R/(x+1)$ and $ R/(x+1) \oplus R/(x)$ are not isomorphic. Similarly, I cannot see why $$R/(x^2);\quad R/(x^2+x);\quad R(x^2+1)$$ are nonisomorphic. I get that $R/(x^2+x) \cong R/(x+1) \oplus R/(x)$ so the decomposition into cyclics is different for this module. However, now I cannot see why this module is not isomorphic to the two direct sums of modules above. Other than that I am lost with this. How do you determine this?

Finally, I get that I should use the classification theorem of finitely generated modules over a PID to help me answer this question. Should I examine the invariant factors to do this and can these factors tell me that these modules are not isomorphic?

Comment: If $f$ is degree 2, then $R / \langle f(x) \rangle \simeq \{ a+bx \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \} \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \simeq R / \langle x \rangle \oplus R / \langle x \rangle$ holds only as isomorphisms of abelian groups or as isomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$-modules, not as isomorphisms of $R$-modules (in the middle two terms, it's unclear how each would even be an $R$-module).

Comment: An $R$-module with exactly four elements is equivalently an endomorphism of the Klein-four group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I am having quite some difficulty determining why these are not isomorphic.

The annihilators of the $R$-modules you listed are, respectively,

$(x^2)$, $(x^2+x)$, $(x^2+x+1)$, $(x^2+1)$, $(x+1)$, and $\{0\}$.

Isomorphic $R$-modules share the same annihilator in $R$.

> Should I examine the invariant factors to do this and can these factors tell me that these modules are not isomorphic?

I suppose that is essentially what I'm suggesting above.  The invariant factors would certainly be helpful for justifying the original candidates, too.  The thing is that there are only finitely many polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$ to work with, and that gives you an exhaustive list of cyclic $R$ modules to build a four-element module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am just curious, if I am given the same problem, but $R=(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]$, and asked to determine the nonisomorphic $R$ modules with $9$ elements, for example, wouldn't $R/(x^2+1)\cong R/(x^2)\cong \mathbb{F}_9$, even though the annihilators are different in this case? Or is this isomorphism only tru as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ modules?

Comment: @Nicky Like I said: isomorphic modules have equal annihilators. That's just a logical consequence off $f(xr)=f(x)r$ given an isomorphism $f$.

Comment: I am really confused wouldn't $R/(x^2+1) \cong R/(x^2+2x+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_9$ but the annihilators are nonisomorphic? You are really helping though. I am just really confused.

Comment: I am thinking about the case $R/(f(x))$ for some irreducible polynomial $f(x)$. This would be a field for all irreducible polynomials, but wouldn't the annihilators be nonisomorphic?

Comment: ok, that is definitely where my misunderstanding is.

Comment: Thank you for trying to make it right.

Comment: @Nicky Let's just stick to $R/(x^2+1)$ and $R/(x^2+2x+1)$.  The one on the right is actually just $R/(x+1)^2$.  Just take $a=1+(x^2+1)$ in the first module and say $f(a)=b$ in the second module.  Multiplying by $(x+1)^2$ on the right, we find out that $f(a(x+1)^2)=0$, so by injectivity $a(x+1)^2=0$, or rather, writing out the quotient module stuff in detail, $1(x+1)^2+(x^2+1)=0+(x^2+1)$.   But that says $(x+1 )^2$ is divisible by $x^2+1$, an absurdity.

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted my earlier comment elevating the need to distinguish between ring homomorphisms and module homomorphisms.   That's part of what's going on here, and I'll mention it again in this comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Yea, I am not good at determining whether modules are isomorphic. There are fewer exercises given to me for that.

Comment: Now you should try just proving it for all modules $M\cong N$, that their annihilators must match.  Take care though that modules with equal annihilators need not be isomorphic! it only goes one way...